# Install latest vlc on centos 5.5

Tags: linux, installation, vlc-media-player, yum, packages

I am using Centos 5.5. When I try,

```
yum install vlc
```

I got vlc version 0.9.9a which is very old with lot of bugs.
Is there a way to get the latest version of VLC?
I have already tried

```
yum update vlc
```

It says "nothing to update" which is not correct as the recent version of VLC is > 2. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.